# Converting [img=URL] to html tags

Tags: php, html, image, str-replace, bbcode

making a basic user submitted CMS and there is all sorts of different image codes that forums use.

So far I have used the following:

```
$text = str_ireplace("[IMG]", "<img class='buildimage' src='", "$text");
$text = str_ireplace("[/IMG]", "'>", "$text");
```

Which works for the normal BBCode image tags which are [img]URL[/img]

But cant think of a way to change e.g using PHP:

```
[img=http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v479/D2BBA/p3.jpg]
```

To a normal HTML image tag. Any help?

Thanks, Craig.

Comment: Please go on and learn about String manipulation before asking a question about it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Comment: **Be careful writing HTML generators like this.** Your current code is vulnerable to script injection through malformed arguments — consider, for example, `[IMG]http://url/to/image' onload='alert(1)[/IMG]`. String replacements are not a substitute for a good parser!

Comment: I also use HTMLPurifier on all the strings before output. The str replacing is just to allow users to copy and paste from forums.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this can be done more efficiently using regex, but in JavaScript and jQuery I believe the following will work:

```
var text = '[img=http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v479/D2BBA/p3.jpg]';
var temp = text.substring(5);
var img = temp.substring(0, temp.length - 1);

var imgTag = $('<img src="' + img + '">');
$('html').append(imgTag);
```

Try it at http://jsfiddle.net/gqayqgyL/.
Or without jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/gqayqgyL/3/.

Comment: Ideally would need this in PHP, just to keep with the rest of the string processing. But this does work so many thanks :)